# How can I get a full rank symmetric submatrix of a symmetric matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, symmetric-matrices

Suppose $A= [a_{i,j}]$ is an $n \times n$ symmetric matrix with real entries 
such that it has precisely $m$ non-zero eigenvalues. 
I was thinking that it must be possible to pick $i_1, ..., i_m$ so that 
the $m \times m$ matrix $[a_{i_a,i_b}]$ is invertible (and all non-zero eigenvalues). I would appreciate if someone could show me how I can prove this. Thank you.

Comment: The answer depends on how you define the rank of a matrix.

Comment: Let me fix the question a little actually.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may prove this by mathematical induction on the size of $A$. The base case where $n=1$ is trivial. In the inductive step, if $m=n$ (i.e. if $A$ is nonsingular), we simply choose the index set $\{1,2,\ldots,n\}$. If $m<n$ (i.e. $A$ is singular), some row of $A$ is a linear combination of the other rows. Without loss of generality, we may assume that the last row of $A$ is a linear combination of the first $n-1$ rows. Thus $\pmatrix{v^T&1}A=0$ for some $v\in\mathbb R^{n-1}$. Now let
$$
A=\pmatrix{X&y\\ y^T&z},\ P=\pmatrix{I&v\\ 0&1}
$$
where $A$ and $P$ have conforming partitions. Since $\pmatrix{v^T&1}A=0$, we have $v^TX+y^T=0$ and $v^Ty+z=0$. In turn, we also have $Xv+y=0$. It follows that
$$
P^TAP
=\pmatrix{I&0\\ v^T&1}\pmatrix{X&y\\ y^T&z}\pmatrix{I&v\\ 0&1}
=\pmatrix{X&y\\ 0&0}\pmatrix{I&v\\ 0&1}
=\pmatrix{X&0\\ 0&0}.
$$
As $P$ is nonsingular, $m=\operatorname{rank}(A)=\operatorname{rank}(P^TAP)=\operatorname{rank}(X)$. Therefore, by induction assumption, $X$ has a nonsingular $m\times m$ principal submatrix. Now the result follows, because each principal submatrix is also a principal submatrix of $A$.

Comment: Thank you for this, btw what is meant by a principal submatrix?

Comment: @JohnnyT. Let $J\subseteq\{1,2,\ldots,n\}$ be an index set. If you remove all rows and columns with indices $j\in J$ from $A$, the resulting submatrix is called a principal submatrix. In your case $J=\{1,2,\ldots,n\}\setminus\{i_1,\ldots,i_m\}$.

Comment: I just realized, if we have a two by two matrix: first row $[0,1]$, second row $[1,0]$, then the statement I was hoping for can't hold...?

Comment: @JohnnyT. Why not? In this case $n=2$ and $A=\pmatrix{0&1\\ 1&0}$, which has $m=2$ nonzero eigenvalues. So, the "$m\times m$ submatrix" is $A$ itself.

Comment: Oh geez, I'm embarrassed! :P